# Update data php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I just started with php and mysql and I've got this scenario. User registers to page and logs in. I use the `$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']` to greet him and all works fine until here. Then I want to display the data related to this logged in user e.g. First Name, Last Name, Address in input fields that he can then edit and update in the database. How do I do this? I found a lot of examples but can't figure out what's best for my scenario when I want to display the data just for the user that logged in. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can start by reading [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: I stated that I found a lot of examples that didn't work for me so to avoid confusing everyone I didn't want to just copy and paste a big bunch of code found on the net but rather try to understand and learn how a simple thing like displaying data should work for my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would want to do something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is using [`MySQLi SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']."'` basically says select all rows from `users` where the `username` equals the session username. So in theory that would return the data for that username session.

To display the column data, you simply need to put your column names into:

`$row['column_name']`

Which can then be `echo`'d out for instance.

Hope this is of use, also in future, please show us [what  you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and I'd suggest reading over the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: ...Not that questions like this are OK

Comment: they are not, but hey, good deed of the day done

Comment: hmmm... just tried and I get this error Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /homepages/..../home.php on line 104

Comment: what error? are you sure you filled out your db connection info? `mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");`

Comment: Loops are not used when you have to fetch data for a single user

Comment: @Mr.Alien you could just set a `LIMIT`, plus I was using this piece of code so he would not have trouble getting more data in the future

Comment: @wannax where have you placed this code?

Comment: @chriz Fine but why LIMIT where you can particularly pick up a single row, less load on database

Comment: @chriz Am sure wannax is using `mysql_()` and not `mysqli()`

Comment: @chriz I placed the code at the top of the page. I get the First Name And Last Name but still get the fatal error. And yes, I'm using mysql

Comment: @wannax make sure that if you are connecting to the database in another file, that it is using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Comment: @chriz Thanks man, fatal error solved. And the code you posted works fine now. Now I need to try and update the data displayed. Will be back soon hopefully.

Comment: thats alright man, research `mysqli update`, that is what you want if you need to update

Answer (score 0):

Where is that other information stored? You need to use the username to search and retrieve them. Assuming they're in a MySQL database, have a look at [tutorials on PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) to safely retrieve entries

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use his user_id.
When he is logged in, you get his information by user_id.

Example:

```
<?php

$user = new User();

//Check if is numeric only
if(is_numeric($_SESSION["user_id"]))
  $user->GetUser((int)$_SESSION["user_id"]);
else
  throw new Exception("Session incorrect");   

class User
{
   public $user_name;
   public $last_name;
   public $address;

   public function __construct()
   {
   }

   public function GetUser($user_id)
   {
      //Get user info from database
      // fill object
     $this->user_name = $result["username"];
     $this->last_name = $result["last_name"];
     $this->address = $result["address"];

     return $this;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: This will bounce over his head as he has stated that he is a beginner

Comment: @Mr. Alien He asked for a how to do. The answer can be for everyone :) I give a small example. Better a good answer as a half answer :)